# Use generator expressions with add_dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have a target called `Foo.Compile` which builds my main program.

```
add_executable(Foo.Compile ...)
```

Then I have a utility target called `Foo.Process` which depends on the executable having already been built and does some stuff.

```
add_custom_target(Foo.Process)
add_dependencies(Foo.Process Foo.Compile)
```

But I only want this to run in release build because it's slow.  So I make a new target called `Foo`, which is what the user actually builds.  In release build this should depend on `Foo.Process`, but in other configurations it should not.  So I thought I could do this:

```
add_custom_target(Foo)
add_dependencies(Foo $<$<CONFIG:Release>:Foo.Process>)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
  The dependency target "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:Foo.Process>" of
  target "Foo" does not exist.
```

The problem seems to be that `add_dependencies` does not support generator expressions, so I thought I'd just use `target_link_libraries`, which I know does.  But then that gives me an error that you cannot use `target_link_libraries` with a utility project.

Note that I cannot use `if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE == Release)` because I need to support multi-config generators like Visual Studio, so I think I have to use a generator expression.

What am I to do?

Comment: for posterity: [link to kitware issue raised by the question author](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19467)